# Calculating criteria occurrence across results per row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to determine on a per row basis, how many of these requests exist at a specific moment in time.

*The date and time are formatted specifically to appear this way in the results, however they are stored in default `yyyy-mm-dd` and `00:00:00.000` formats respectively in the database*

`Request Data:`

```
ID      |   CDate       |   CTime   |   LDate       |   LTime
---------------------------------------------------------------
230700  |   13/07/2016  |   6:52am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:21am 
746970  |   13/07/2016  |   7:05am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:10am 
746971  |   13/07/2016  |   7:09am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:09am 
746972  |   13/07/2016  |   7:16am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:27am
746973  |   13/07/2016  |   7:20am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:29am
```

`CTime` refers to Issue Creation time, with `LTime` referring to the time the issue has been logged into by a user.

I wish to add a new column at the end of these results, based on the results of the entire query.  The new column would count how many issues are visible at any given time.  Issues are visible as soon as they are created, and disappear when a user logs into the request, creating an `LTime` entry.

In this example, we will use the 2nd row of data for `ID: 746970`.  We can see that the creation time was `7:05am`, however the issue wasn't logged into until `7:10am`.  At that login time, 2 other issues had already been created, however hadn't yet been logged into (`230700` and `746971`), with a creation time of `6:52am`/`7:21am` and `7:09am`/`7:09am` respectively.  As such, the new column would report a value of `3` for number of issues visible at the time of logging in.

My thought process so far leads me to believe this would need a 2-3 part query, potentially storing results in a Temp Table.  The first part of the query would obtain the results as they are shown above (already created).  The second part of the query would determine on a 'per row' basis how many rows have a `CTime` less than the each row's `LTime`.  The 3rd query would then run another check on the results of the 2nd query to count the number of rows where the `LTime` of the current row is equal to or less than the `LTime` of other rows.

The results upon running this would appear as below. ***The bracketed text would not show in the results, merely included to show working.***

`New data:`

```
ID      |   CDate       |   CTime   |   LDate       |   LTime   |   #Active
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
230700  |   13/07/2016  |   6:52am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:21am  | 3 (230700, 746972, 746973)
746970  |   13/07/2016  |   7:05am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:10am  | 2 (230700, 746970)
746971  |   13/07/2016  |   7:09am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:09am  | 3 (230700, 746970, 746971)
746972  |   13/07/2016  |   7:16am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:27am  | 2 (746972, 746973)
746973  |   13/07/2016  |   7:20am  |   13/07/2016  |   7:29am  | 1 (746973)
```

I'm at a loss on this one, I know the logic for it, but can't for the life of me put it into MS SQL code.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `The 3rd row of data also has a login time of 7:21am, however as the CTime is greater than the LTime of the 2nd row, the 2nd row will not count this as an active request.` I'm unsure how you get `2 (746970, 746971)` for the 7:09-7:09 one.

Comment: I have edited the original post for clarity.  It originally did have a login time of `7:21am`, however I edited this and forgot to review wording I had used prior to the edit, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear how the expected result was produced. Why does 746970 count as "active" for 746971, but 230700 doesn't count as active? EDIT: Should the criteria be any other row where CTime+CDate >= this row's CTime+CDate and LTime+LDate < this row's LTime+LDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'm going to say is that you should consider altering your table such that the DATE and TIME fields are not separate. Unless you're running a whole bunch of queries that *only* care about time or *only* care about date and you have indexes built around this, you're better off using a single DATETIME column - it makes running queries that require both date and time so much easier.

Moving on to what I believe is the solution to your problem (assuming the criteria for "active" is correct)... The short answer is that you don't need any temporary tables or anything (my solution uses a CTE but it doesn't even need that):

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, CDate DATE NOT NULL, CTime TIME NOT NULL, LDate DATE NOT NULL, LTime TIME NOT NULL)
INSERT @ VALUES (230700, '2016-07-13', '06:52:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:21:00.000')
, (746970, '2016-07-13', '07:05:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:10:00.000')
, (746971, '2016-07-13', '07:09:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:09:00.000')
, (746972, '2016-07-13', '07:16:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:27:00.000')
, (746973, '2016-07-13', '07:20:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:29:00.000');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID
         , CDate + CAST(CTime AS DATETIME) CDateTime
         , LDate + CAST(LTime AS DATETIME) LDateTime
    FROM @)
SELECT T.ID, T.CDateTime, T.LDateTime, Z.ActiveCount
FROM CTE T
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(255)) 
           + ' (' +
           STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(255))
            FROM CTE
            WHERE CDateTime <= T.LDateTime
            AND LDateTime >= T.LDateTime
            ORDER BY ID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') + ')'
           -- COUNT(*) -- this just produces the number
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CDateTime <= T.LDateTime
    AND LDateTime >= T.LDateTime) Z(ActiveCount)
```

If you need to keep the date and time fields separate, the statement can be rewritten as:

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, CDate DATE NOT NULL, CTime TIME NOT NULL, LDate DATE NOT NULL, LTime TIME NOT NULL)
INSERT @ VALUES (230700, '2016-07-13', '06:52:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:21:00.000')
, (746970, '2016-07-13', '07:05:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:10:00.000')
, (746971, '2016-07-13', '07:09:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:09:00.000')
, (746972, '2016-07-13', '07:16:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:27:00.000')
, (746973, '2016-07-13', '07:20:00.000', '2016-07-13', '07:29:00.000');

SELECT T.ID
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), T.CDate, 103) CDate
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), T.CTime, 100) CTime
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), T.LDate, 103) LDate
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), T.LTime, 100) LTime
     , Z.ActiveCount
FROM @ T
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) -- this just produces the number
    FROM @
    WHERE CDate + CAST(CTime AS DATETIME) <= T.LDate + CAST(T.LTime AS DATETIME)
    AND LDate + CAST(LTime AS DATETIME) >= T.LDate + CAST(T.LTime AS DATETIME)) Z(ActiveCount)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the entire report consists of 400-600 requests, the 5 provided were merely a sample size for ease of viewing.  The time also ranges from 6:00am to 11:00pm, so adding each of those values into an Insert statement isn't feasible, as these times change daily.

I have also edited the original post again to update the 3rd result, this is the reason that I am after a query to do this for me, as I am human and make mistakes.

Comment: @Draemon So is the logic in the where condition incorrect? I thought, for example, that at 7:09 (the time the third row was "logged"), there would be three open ones (itself, row2 and row1, because row1 and row2 were both created but not logged at 7:09). Is this incorrect? Also the number of rows isn't important, really. The query would work for any number of rows. It's just that the logic in the where condition needs to be correct.

Comment: The where statement is indeed sound, props for understanding my confusing data lol.  I'm currently using a query to obtain the results I am after, is your query something I would be able to incorporate into my existing query?  Or would I need to store my original query in a table first and then run this against the new table?

Comment: The results of the query could theoretically be treated as a subquery as part of a bigger query... e.g. `SELECT X, Y, Z FROM otherPartOfQuery JOIN (SELECT T.ID, T.CDate, C.CTime, T.LDate, T.LTime, Z.ActiveCount FROM myTable T OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE CDate + CAST(CTime AS DATETIME) <= T.LDate + CAST(T.LTime AS DATETIME) AND LDate + CAST(LTime AS DATETIME) >= T.LDate + CAST(T.LTime AS DATETIME)) Z(ActiveCount)) insertTableAlias ON insertTableAlias.field = otherQuery.field`

Comment: @Draemon, Alternatively, you could put the whole thing in a CTE to be part of a bigger query or put it in a table-valued function to call it at any time.

Comment: I have tried a number of different ways to try integrating your query into mine, however I am coming up short on each occasion.  I have pasted the entire query here http://pastebin.com/ZuTj31T6.  This query consists of subqueries and a number of other table joins to obtain all of the data I need, which is making it difficult for me to figure out where to join the data with your query.